# Infinite series convergence test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

Test the convergence of the following series:

$${\sqrt{n+1}-1\over (n+2)^3 -1} +... \infty$$

(This is a problem I got on my test today, I constructed a similar series without the -1 part and showed that since the quotient of the nth (n tending to infinity) term of the constructed series and the nth term of this series is non-zero, they behave alike and converge as tested by p series test, p = 5/2).

Comment: Velcome to our site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-1}{(n+2)^3-1}
&=\frac{1}{n^{5/2}}\frac{\sqrt{1+1/n}-\sqrt{1/n}}{(1+2/n)^3-1/n^3}\\
&\sim\frac1{n^{5/2}}
\end{align}
$$
your method looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-1}{(n+2)^3-1}&=\frac{(\sqrt{n+1}-1)(\sqrt{n+1}+1)}{((n+2)^3-1)(\sqrt{n+1}+1)}\\
&=\frac{n}{((n+2)^3-1)(\sqrt{n+1}+1)}\\
&<\frac{n}{n^3}\\
&=\frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align}
Using the p-test, $\frac{1}{n^2}$ converges, and since $0<\frac{n}{((n+2)^3-1)(\sqrt{n+1}+1)}<\frac{1}{n^2}$, using the comparison test, the original series must also converge.

Comment: Hmm, at-least I wasn't wrong about the behavior.. Can you comment on my solution (mentioned below the question problem).

Comment: @uest1075375 I don't know what you mean by the $n$-th terms behaving alike and being non-zero :P. I'm not an expert in this topic...

Comment: the quotient test if I'm not mistaken says that if the quotient of nth terms of two series is non-zero, the series diverge or converge together.

Comment: OK, I haven't heard of that... I just finished Calculus I this semester, and I don't think they went too deep into series/sequences.

Answer (score 0):

It is clear that $\frac {\sqrt{n+1}-1}{(n+2)^3-1}\sim \frac{1}{n^\frac{5}{2}}$ as ${n\to\infty}$ . Since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$  converges so that the series must be converge

Comment: actually, the terms are asymptotic to $1/n^{5/2}$.